# backup aws ec2 to separate account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to backup my AWS snapshots to a completely separate AWS account for additional security (if my AWS credentials were acquired someone could delete all my snapshots and volumes). But I'm a bit stumped on how to do this.

There doesn't seem to be a way to store a volume or snapshot in S3 such that another user could access that data in s3 and store it in a separate AWS account.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your snapshot permissions and add your other account's account number. Under EC2, go to Snapshots, right-click on the snapshot you want to share and then choose Snapshot Permissions.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=270059